# How to analyze Malware when it infected all my exe files

Tags: analysis, malware

I'm analyzing a trojan on my virtualbox win7-32. when I run the trojan, it infected all exe files,consequently I could not use any malware analyzer program (process monitor or process hacker...) to analyze it to get result.How can I handle it?

Comment: Can't you analyse before it infect exes ?

Comment: I need to run it to get complete results.process monitor or process hacker don't show anything relates to the torjan activity.I got some results before running it,but I need more.

Comment: What king of informations do you want to get on that trojan ?

Comment: creates which files in it's execution folder, create dlls in system32 folder, change registry key, see it's mutex objects, see open ports, network connection... :)

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of way of getting these informations. You can: decompile the trojan and analyse it's behavior from the raw bytecode/sourcecode. Observe change in directory (many tools, from git to specialized software ...). Dump registry and compare after trojan action. Use native cmd line to see ports and connexion (with `netstat -a -n -o` or piece of software).
As you are not providing clear and full information on your problem (that's where the downvotes happen), I doubt anyone would help you more on this (transparency is a key to get help).

Also, depending of your situation, I would advice hiring a security expert that will be able to do the deep investigation for you.

Finally it is very probable that you can find details on this trojan on security database from it's simple name.

Comment: what if there are no file??it just infect all exe in my pc,but there are no main file here